# QT Windows Desktop GUI program crashes in Release mode but does not crash in Debug mode

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface, release

I have this strange problem where running the release version of my GUI app on Windows crashes at startup and prints out the following (abridged) output:

```
Starting C:........\build-WindowsUI-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2010_OpenGL_32bit-Release\release\WindowsUI.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:.............\build-WindowsUI-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2010_OpenGL_32bit-Release\release\WindowsUI.exe crashed
```

There is no other information given. Compiler output seems normal and no crash detailed information is printed. When I run the debug version: everything is fine. The GUI runs normally and no problems encountered.

Has anyone else encountered something like this before? I'm stuck here.

Comment: Have you tried to do a clean build after switching to Release mode?

Comment: It is often the case that a program which crashes in release, but not debug is due to uninitialised variables. Debug builds can set the memory of those variables to zero, whereas a release build will not.

Comment: And be sure to not mix Debug and Release Versions of DLLs! OpenCV has a very well known bug that crashes release versions if linked to a debug dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mailerdaimon!

I took at look at my QT project file.  In my .pro file I tell the linker to use specific dlls for release and debug mode.  Based on your idea, I tried commenting out the sections that specify the dlls based on which type of executable was being outputted:

```
#win32|win64:debug {
# need to link DLL versions of library for Debug
#LIBS += -L"../ThirdParty/thirdPartyDlls" \
#
#         -lthirdPartyD
#
#}

#win32|win64:release {
# need to link DLL versions of  library for release
LIBS += -L"../ThirdParty/thirdPartyDlls" \

         -lthirdParty

#}
```

And now release mode works!  I guess I used the wrong syntax in the .pro file or maybe it's a bug in Qt Creator.  Either way I got it working now :).  Thanks again!